# How to number examples automatically?

Tags: enumerate, examples

I have document with 30 math examples. How do I number these examples automatically? Without using the list

```
 \begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}
```

like

```
Example 1
blah blah

Example 2
blah blah
```

and so on?

Comment: `\begin{equation}1=0\end{equation}` will number the equation as 1,2,...

Comment: What does one example look like (LaTeX source is better than a picture here).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do the examples have to be each on a line of its own?

Comment: Could you please edit your question title to something that gives people a sense of what your question is about. Also perhaps a place to start is [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693). Also, for math formatting, the mathmode documentation is very useful.

Answer (score 10):

- define new counter
- define new environment with title and number
- increment counter before its use

Something like this:

```
\newcounter{xmpl}
\newenvironment{example}
    {\noindent
     \refstepcouter{xmpl}
     \textbf{Example \thexmpl }
    }{\par\noindent%
      \ignorespacesafterend}
```

and then use as:

```
\begin{example} 
< content of the example>
\end{example}
```

**Addendum:**
More simpler and straightforward solution is consider *Christian Hupfer* comment below: use of `newtheorem`.

- load package `amsthm`
- declare example environments as `\newtheorem{example}{Example}`
- use it as shown above

More details and concise description about theorems like environments you can find in [Wikibook LaTeX/Theorems](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems). Sorry, because I didn't recall for this usual approach before.

**Addedndum 2:**
You can also use `enumerate` environment. Package `enumitem` offer simple redefinition of labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=Exercise \arabic*]
\item \lipsum*[11]
\[
c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
\]
\item blah blah
\[
a = \sqrt{c^2 - b^2}
\]
\item blah blah
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

For other possibilities for formatting of enumerate environment see package documentation.

Of course this recent solution has sense if examples are organised as list, i.e. examples follow one after another.

[image]

Comment: You could also mention the usual `\newtheorem` approach, `\newtheorem{example}{Example}`, for example (pun intented ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you very much for comment. I consider it in my answer.